# WebGL: unexpected effects in canvas when setting alpha lower than 1.0

Tags: html, css, canvas, webgl, alpha

It seems like canvas' alpha depends on the CSS Background color (tested on Chrome 60 and Firefox 47).

#### Case 1: Background: black, canvas: red with 10% alpha

```
body {background-color: #000000} /* or any other parent DOM element */
```

Setting Canvas Color to red with 10% alpha

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1);
```

has this result:

[image: black background]

**-> I expect red to be 90% darker**

I got the same result after puting alpha to 100%:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
return;
```

#### Case 2: Background: white, canvas: red with 10% alpha

[image: white background]

**-> it looks correct**

#### Case 3: Background: blue, canvas: red with 10% alpha

[image: blue background]

**-> it looks like red part is more than 10%**

### Is there any Color Blending mode, which I'm not aware of?

(These tests were the same on Firefox and Chrome)

Comment: this has been answered many times. I fact the linked answer was on the right "related questions" links

Comment: others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273858/how-to-make-webgl-canvas-transparent, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636837/math-formula-for-color-and-alpha-in-webgl, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341564/webgl-how-to-correctly-blend-alpha-channel-png/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217189/alpha-blending-in-webgl-works-not-correctly, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724317/webgl-colors-and-alpha, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362023/webgl-why-does-transparent-canvas-show-clearcolor-color-component-when-alpha-is

Comment: cont... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362023/webgl-why-does-transparent-canvas-show-clearcolor-color-component-when-alpha-is

Comment: It solves my problem. I'm ashamed to not have found these questions.
Thank you for your fast help. You are really everywhere where someone types in "WebGL" :)

Comment: Let's blame SO's search :D